# Problem with writing to file second time, Python3

Tags: python

I have created a phonebook with `tkinker` using `Python 3.6`
When I add persons to phonebook it save it to a file.

When I load the program again it loads the file as it should.
If I add 2 person at first run, all works fine.
Second run, I add one person and it adds an empty line at index 1 and adds the person below as it should.
Third run, I add one person, it adds a new line at index 1 and a person last in the list. 
Now I get 2 empty lines.

I can't figure out why it creates an empty space at index 1 . It should not do it.

Here is the code, comments are in Swedish so sorry about it.

How I write to the file is in function `lägg_till()`
It will auto create kontakter.txt when you run it first time. 
"Lägg till" means add in Sweden and "Avsluta" is quit the program.

```
from tkinter import *
import os.path


root = Tk()
root.geometry("640x640+200+100")
root.title("Telefon listan")

def avsluta():
    quit()

def spara():
    #Spara kontakter till fil.
    name = entry_1.get()
    mobil = entry_2.get()
    if name == "" or mobil == "" :
        pass
    else:
        with open("kontakter.txt","w") as file:
            file.write("\n".join(kontakter.get(0,END)))

def ta_bort():
    # Ta bort kontakter,genom att välja index av element och sparar värdet i variabel index.
    index = kontakter.curselection()
    print(index)
    kontakter.delete(index)

def lägg_till():
    # Ta inmatade värden från name,mobil och spara i kontakter.
    # Använder .get() för att hämta
    name = entry_1.get()
    mobil = entry_2.get().replace(" ", "") # Använder replace för att rensa whitespace
    # Varning när alla värden inte är ifyllda
    if name == "" or mobil == "" :
        label_error.config(text="Alla fälten är inte ifyllda")

    else:
    # trycka in dessa i kontakter med .insert() END för slutet av listan, dvs index "kan vara 0,1,2,3"
        #Rensar error fältet innan man lägger till kontakten
        label_error.config(text="")
        kontakter.insert(END,name + " - " + mobil)
        # Rensa fältet efter lägg till
        entry_1.delete(0,END)
        entry_2.delete(0,END)
        kontakt = kontakter.get(0,END)
        with open("kontakter.txt","w") as file:
            file.write("\n".join(kontakt))


def uppdatera():
    # Hämta det markerade data
    index = kontakter.curselection()
    name = entry_1.get()
    mobil = entry_2.get()
    # Varning när alla värden inte är ifyllda
    if name == "" or mobil == "" :
        label_error.config(text="Alla fälten är inte ifyllda")
    else:
        # trycka in dessa i kontakter med .insert() END för slutet av listan, dvs index "kan vara 0,1,2,3"
        #Rensar error fältet innan man lägger till kontakten
        label_error.config(text="")
        # Raderar det ifyllda data
        kontakter.delete(index)
        #Skriver nytt
        kontakter.insert(index,name + "-" + mobil)
        entry_1.delete(0,END)
        entry_2.delete(0,END)

# Skapar frame
#Namn
fram_1 = Frame(root)
fram_1.pack()
#Mobil
fram_2 = Frame(root)
fram_2.pack()
#Knappar
fram_3 = Frame(root)
fram_3.pack()
# Listbox
fram_4 = Frame(root)
fram_4.pack()

#Skapar label
#Namn
label_1 = Label(fram_1,text="Name:")
label_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
#Mobil
label_2 = Label(fram_2,text="Mobil:")
label_2.grid(row=1,column=0)


# Skapar entry
#namn
entry_1 = Entry(fram_1)
entry_1.grid(row=0,column=1)
#Mobil
entry_2 = Entry(fram_2)
entry_2.grid(row=1,column=2,)

# Kolla om filen finns, annars skapa den, behöver importera os.path
if not os.path.exists("kontakter.txt"):
    open('kontakter.txt', 'w').close()
else:
    pass


# Läsa från fil
data = []
with open("kontakter.txt" ,"r") as fil:
    for line in fil:
        data += [line]


# Listbox
kontakter = Listbox(fram_4,height=8,width=40,bg="pink")
kontakter.grid(row=0,column=0)
# Lägger till kontakter , första värdet är index följt av värde,
kontakter.insert(END,)

#Läsa in från fil
for i in range(len(data)):
    kontakter.insert(i+0 , data[i])

# Error
label_error = Label(root,text="",fg="red")
label_error.pack()

# Knappar
# knapp Lägg till
button_1 = Button(fram_3,text="Lägg till",command=lägg_till)
button_1.grid(row=0,column=0)
# knapp edit
button_2 = Button(fram_3,text="Uppdatera",command=uppdatera)
button_2.grid(row=0,column=1)
# Knapp delete
button_3 = Button(fram_3,text="Radera",command=ta_bort)
button_3.grid(row=0,column=2)
# Knapp avsluta
button_4 = Button(fram_3,text="Avsluta",command=avsluta)
button_4.grid(row=0,column=3)
button_5 = Button(fram_3,text="Spara",command=spara)
button_5.grid(row=0,column=4)


root.attributes("-topmost", True)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `lägg_till()` when you open the file use `ab` instead of `w`:

```
with open("kontakter.txt","ab") as file:
        file.write("\n".join(kontakt))
```

Comment: I got following error file.write("\n".join(kontakter.get(0,END)))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: But I made one fix in the read file.

# Läsa från fil
data = []
with open("kontakter.txt" ,"r") as fil:
    for line in fil.readlines():
        data += [line.strip()] #.strip() fix the problem
    fil.close()

Answer (score 0):

By adding .strip() , I made workaround, but I think problem is still there.

```
# Läsa från fil
data = []
with open("kontakter.txt" ,"r") as fil:
    for line in fil.readlines():
        data += [line.strip()] #.strip() fix the problem
    fil.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your program is `kontakt = kontakter.get(0,END)`, which returns your data as follows :

```
('1 - 1\n', '2 - 2', '3 - 3')
```

Note that the third entry `(3 - 3)` is made after the GUI was closed once. By joining together with `'\n'.join()`, you get an additional space character:

```
'1 - 1\n\n2 - 2\n3 - 3\n'
```

I don't know the exact reason why this only happens if you close the program once.

You can avoid this conflict by using 'a' instead of 'w', which simply appends the string in the text file.

```
with open("kontakter.txt","a") as file:
    file.write(name + " - " + mobil + '\n')
```